# Lazy Racket on REPL

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation

I can change Racket from strict to [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) using [`#lang lazy`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/), but that only works in a module. How can I use it in the REPL console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the language in the REPL, you can use the `-I` flag. For example, to use the `lazy` language, run `racket -iI lazy`:

```
$ racket -iI lazy
Welcome to Racket v6.7.0.3.
> (define fibs
    (list* 1 1 (map + fibs (cdr fibs))))
> fibs
#<promise:fibs>
> (list-ref fibs 10)
89
```

Comment: Thanks. `(car (cons 1 (/ 1 0)))` also gets `1`  instead of `zero division error` now.